# Отобразить все медиафайлы в wordpress для конкретной роли

Tags: wordpress

Все медиафайлы в библиотеке отображаются только для Администратора. Редактор же видит исключительно только свои загрузки.

Необходимо отобразить все загрузки для редактора.

Плагины типа Role Access и Restrict Access Media Library не помогают.

Comment: По умолчанию редакторам доступна вся медиатека. Ищи кто это запретил.

Comment: Версия 5.2.4. Юзер с ролью editor не видит чужих Медиафайлов. Отключал все плагины - так же не видит.

Comment: Если переключиться на стандартную тему, проблема останется?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос. Вставляем это в functions.php

```
// Show only own items in media uploader
add_filter('ajax_query_attachments_args', 'sb_my_attachments_only');

function sb_my_attachments_only($query) {
 $query['author'] = $user_id;
 return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','users_own_attachments');

function users_own_attachments( $wp_query_obj ) {

    global $current_user, $pagenow;

    $is_attachment_request = ($wp_query_obj->get('post_type')=='attachment');

    if( !$is_attachment_request )
        return;

    if( !is_a( $current_user, 'WP_User') )
        return;

    if( !in_array( $pagenow, array( 'upload.php', 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) )
        return;

    if( !current_user_can('delete_pages') )
        $wp_query_obj->set('author', $current_user->ID );

    return;
}
```

Comment: Благодарю. Закинул в functions, но безрезультатно.